# Trying to identify specific VHS filters used here

Tags: effects, filter, vhs

[image]

A slightly blurry VHS filter:

And a screenshot from a puppetcombo game called murderhouse. They seem to have blue-yellow accents and are slightly blurry.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is chromatic aberation. On original VHS it comes from the way the colour signals are stored at lower fidelity than the luminance signals:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHS#Video_recording

> VHS tapes have approximately 3 MHz of video bandwidth and 400 kHz of chroma bandwidth, which is lower than the 6 MHz in NTSC broadcasts, and the 5 MHz in Type C videotape. The luminance (black and white) portion of the video is recorded as a frequency modulated, with a down-converted "color under" chroma (color) signal recorded directly at the baseband.

You can generate something similar by separating out the red, green, and blue channels of your image, then messing with them, by distorting, blurring, or adding noise to them, then recombining them.  There are lots of plugins that can do this - these two are good examples for After Effects / Premiere:

- https://aescripts.com/bad-tv/
- https://www.maxon.net/en/red-giant-complete/universe/vhs